# SQL to exclude holidays, weekends and future days

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have created a stored procedure as below:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE reminders
AS

BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @MyDate    DATE, 
@FirstDate DATE, 
@LastDate  DATE 

SELECT @MyDate = Getdate()


 SELECT @FirstDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), Dateadd(dd, -( Day(@mydate) - 1 ), @mydate), 100),  @LastDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), Dateadd(dd, -( Day( Dateadd(mm, 1, @mydate)) ), 
 Dateadd(mm, 1, @mydate)), 100) 


DECLARE @AllDates TABLE 
( 
datevalue DATE
) 
DECLARE @Lastday INT 

SET @Lastday = Datepart(d, @LastDate) 

DECLARE @Days INT 

SET @Days = 1 


WHILE @Days <= @Lastday 
BEGIN 
INSERT INTO @AllDates 
SELECT @FirstDate 

SET @FirstDate = Dateadd(d, 1, @FirstDate) 
SET @Days = @Days + 1 
END 


SELECT AD.datevalue 
FROM   @AllDates AD 
LEFT OUTER JOIN EmpLog EL 
ON AD.datevalue = EL.Date
LEFT OUTER JOIN holiday H 
ON AD.datevalue = H.Date

WHERE  EL.Date IS NULL 
AND H.Date IS NULL  
AND DATENAME(dw,AD.DateValue) NOT IN ('Saturday','Sunday')

END
```

What i need to have is the output should not include the future days.
Ex Date today is `12-21-2012`, the output of that code includes 12-22-2012 to 12-31-2012,
and also, i want the code to output 16 days only before the current date. 
Ex. Date today is `12-21-2012` so the output of that code will be November 30 to December 21 excluded the holidays and weekends.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Justine - Use this procedure. It accepts start date and end date as input parameters. It will give you the desired results between those 2 dates.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE reminders

@FirstDate DATE, 
@LastDate  DATE 

AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @AllDates TABLE 
( 
datevalue DATE
) 

WHILE @FirstDate <= @Lastdate 
BEGIN 
INSERT INTO @AllDates 
SELECT @FirstDate 
SET @FirstDate = Dateadd(d, 1, @FirstDate) 
END 


SELECT AD.datevalue 
FROM   @AllDates AD 
LEFT OUTER JOIN EmpLog EL 
ON AD.datevalue = EL.Date
LEFT OUTER JOIN holiday H 
ON AD.datevalue = H.Date

WHERE  EL.Date IS NULL 
AND H.Date IS NULL  
AND DATENAME(dw,AD.DateValue) NOT IN ('Saturday','Sunday')

END
```

Raj

Comment: Sir, i have changed the date, January 4,2013. and the output includes only Jan 2, 3 and 4. I need 16 days before jan 4. So the output should be dec 12 to Jan 4.

Comment: you have to call the SP twice - once with Dec 31 2012 and once with January 4, 2013 and then combine the results into one

Comment: is there no way to declare like this?

dateadd(d,-16,getDate())

calling two stored proc will output me last month(Dec) and January not the 16 days before the current date

Comment: Justine - In your original question you said - "What i need to have is the output should not include the future days" and now you are saying something else. Please post what exactly you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

In SQLServer2005+ use recursive CTE

```
ALTER PROCEDURE reminders
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
  DECLARE @MyDate date = GETDATE()
  ;WITH cte AS
   (
    SELECT @MyDate AS datevalue,
           1 AS [count_all_days],
           CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, DATEADD(dd, - 1, @MyDate)) IN ('Saturday', 'Sunday') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS [count_week_days]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(dd, - [count_all_days], @MyDate), 
           [count_all_days] + 1,
           CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, DATEADD(dd, - [count_all_days], @MyDate)) IN ('Saturday', 'Sunday') THEN [count_week_days] + 1 ELSE [count_week_days] END
    FROM cte
    WHERE [count_all_days] - [count_week_days] < 16
    )
    SELECT AD.datevalue
    FROM cte AD LEFT JOIN EmpLog EL ON AD.datevalue = EL.Date
                LEFT JOIN holiday H ON AD.datevalue = H.Date
    WHERE EL.Date IS NULL AND H.Date IS NULL  AND DATENAME(dw, AD.DateValue) NOT IN ('Saturday', 'Sunday')
END
```

Comment: Sir, How can I filter this dates using EmpID, so that when I have logged in I can only see the dates of my account.

Comment: @Justine What is EmpID? and why EmpID absent in your question

Comment: ALTER PROCEDURE reminders
@EmpID int 

//query goes here

I added the EmpID so that I can filter only the dates for my account.

Comment: Example:
Table Account(EmpID,Username,Password)
my EmpID = 1
so when I logged in .. I can only see in reminders table is the dates for EmpID 1.

Comment: @Justine How table account association with other tables?